# Prevent website from blocking bookmarklet script

Tags: firefox, javascript, discord

While using some websites, I often use a [language bar bookmarklet](https://abrudz.github.io/lb/bqn) to type strange unicode symbols to show BQN code.

When i click the bookmarklet on the discord web app, the following error shows up in the Mozilla Firefox DevTools console.

[image]

[This is the bookmarklet's internal code.](https://github.com/abrudz/lb/blob/master/bqn.js)

I think there may be a way to modify the script to work on discord, but my google searches have given no results.

Is there a way to prevent a site from doing this blocking via settings, or additional plugins?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to prevent a site from doing this blocking via settings, or additional plugins?

Per an answer to this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323631/how-to-override-content-security-policy-while-including-script-in-browser-js-con), it is possible to disable [Content Security Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) browser-wide in Firefox by setting `about:config` → `security.csp.enable` to `false`:

[image: Content Security Policy Settings - Firefox 89.0.1 - Screenshot]

This setting was confirmed to still be available as of Firefox 89.0.1 (June 2021).

**As that answer notes, however, this is exceptionally dangerous for general web browsing.**

Other options could (possibly) include:

- Filtering incoming response headers via an HTTP proxy (as an incoming response header from the server is how the browser knows to follow a given policy).
- Using some plugin or extension (as you suggest), though there seems to be debate on whether or not this would actually work.
- Running your script as a [TamperMonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/)/[GreaseMonkey](https://www.greasespot.net/) userscript as suggested in response to this [Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/586063/how-to-disable-csp-in-firefox-for-just-bookmarklets).